# Recognizing M16 connector

Tags: cable-assemblies

I had a thermowell with DS18B20 temperature sensor. At some point the sensor stopped working properly and was disturbing the bus, so I wanted to change it. Here are the photos of the assembly:

[image: Cable part]

[image: Thermowell]

[image]

On the last figure, one can see the thermowell and the destroyed male connector which was fixed in the hole with epoxy.

Does anybody knows the name of this connector type. The closest I could come is M16, but I couldn't find the connectors shown in the figures.

Comment: Looks like DIN?

Comment: I searched for somehink like M16 DIN connector and found that some people called something like this "Aviator Connector". How do you call in english plug which is not meant for panel mounting but for being in hole fixed with glue or epoxy?

Comment: The black cable connector looks like DIN or possibly 5 pin XLR. The sensor looks like XLR. Take measurements with a caliper and compare.